# libssh2 - Preserve mtime using scp

Tags: scp, libssh2

I have a problem with preserving mtime.

This piece of code does not set my mtime. it sets the current time on the remote instead.

I am using the same code as in example https://www.libssh2.org/examples/scp_write.html

Except for the line 166

```
channel = libssh2_scp_send64(session, scppath, fileinfo.st_mode & 0777, (size_t)fileinfo.st_size, 1505225516l, 1505225516l);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're opening your ssh connection and invoking scp on the remote system.

Comment: Edited. I tried an example, which my code follows, and it still doesn't work.